# Not able to use MockK in Android Espresso UI Testing

Tags: kotlin, mocking, android-espresso, coded-ui-tests, mockk

I am getting a error when trying to use MockK in UI test which was perfectly working in Unittest cases

```
MockK could not self-attach a jvmti agent to the current VM
```

**Full error report**

```
Caused by: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentException: MockK could not self-attach a jvmti agent to the current VM. This feature is required for inline mocking.
This error occured due to an I/O error during the creation of this agent: java.io.IOException: Unable to dlopen libmockkjvmtiagent.so: dlopen failed: library "libmockkjvmtiagent.so" not found

Potentially, the current VM does not support the jvmti API correctly
at io.mockk.proxy.android.AndroidMockKAgentFactory.init(AndroidMockKAgentFactory.kt:67)
at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<init>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:46)
at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:186)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to dlopen libmockkjvmtiagent.so: dlopen failed: library "libmockkjvmtiagent.so" not found
at dalvik.system.VMDebug.nativeAttachAgent(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.VMDebug.attachAgent(VMDebug.java:693)
at android.os.Debug.attachJvmtiAgent(Debug.java:2617)
at io.mockk.proxy.android.JvmtiAgent.<init>(JvmtiAgent.kt:48)
at io.mockk.proxy.android.AndroidMockKAgentFactory.init(AndroidMockKAgentFactory.kt:40)
```

Let me know is there any other way to initialize the MockK to make use in Espresso

When tried to add

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoVersion"
```

Observed this error

2 files found with path 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'.
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
for more information

**Versions**

```
mockk version = 1.12.4
Android = 32
kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
```

**Code which causes this issue when added in android UI testcases(Espresso)**

```
val presenter = mockk<LoginPresenter>()

val view = mockk<LoginView>()
```

**How to perform a mock api call like this**

```
val presenter = mockk<LoginPresenter>()
    val view = mockk<LoginView>()


onView(withId(R.id.button_login)).perform(loginClick())
```

But i want mock api to be called
instead of loginClick() in **perform()** can i call some how the below execution
so that my app uses mock api's
or is there any way to make my entire testcase file use mockk data

```
every { presenter.onLoginButtonClicked("bc@mail.com","Abc123")  } returns  view.onCognitoLoginSuccess()
```

Comment: What versions of mockk, Android, Kotlin are you working with? Can you include some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @aSemy Updated versions in the post

Comment: Can you try MockK 1.12.5? If that doesn't work, then can you make an issue? https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/new

Comment: Hi i tried MockK 1.12.5 and this error is not reproduced thanks, i have a query updated in post

Comment: @aSemy how to initialize MockK in espresso UI testing

Answer (score 19):

For me adding this solved the problem:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    packagingOptions {
      jniLibs {
        useLegacyPackaging = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found this [here](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/297#issuecomment-901924678). Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same issue with `MockK` version 1.13.8. This answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Accorfing to [here](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/819) :

> Instrumented Android tests are all failing due to issue with mockk
> **1.12.4**

I used `io.mockk:mockk-android:1.12.4` and i have same issue..

**SOLUTION:**
I change the version of io.mockk:mockk-android to **1.12
3** and test runed fine for me

```
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.12.3"
```